# Disappearing objects in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, collections

I have a problem with ArrayList. I add user in view, user is added but after closed window AddUserController my list is empty. This is strange. There is code:

```
public class AddUserController extends MainController implements Initializable {

private MainPanelController mainControl;
@FXML
private Label UserErrorLabel;
@FXML
private Button UserNameOkButton;

@FXML
private AnchorPane AddUserAnchor;

@FXML
private TextField UserNameTextField;

@Override
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
    addUser();
}
public void addUser(){
    UserNameOkButton.setOnAction(x->{

        String message=getModelLogic().addUserToLogic(UserNameTextField.getText());
        UserErrorLabel.setTextFill(Color.RED);
        UserErrorLabel.setText(message);    

    });
}
public void setMainControl(MainPanelController mainPanel){
    mainControl=mainPanel;
}

}
```

There is class for my logic, i use method addUserToLogic:
    public class ModelLogic implements IApplicationLogic{

```
//***USER LIST, MYSQL, CATEGORYLIST***//
public  UserList userList = new UserList();// object of class UserList which handle list of all users
private  MySQLDatabase mySQL = new MySQLDatabase();//mySQL object to handle Database
private CategoryList categoryList = new CategoryList();// object of class CategoryList which handle list of all categories
private String msg;

//***CONSTRUCTOR**//
//public ModelLogic(){
    //serializeFromFile(categoryList,"CategoryList.obj");
//}

//***GETTERS AND SETTERS***//
public UserList getAllUsers() {
    return userList;
}
public MySQLDatabase getMySQL() {
    return mySQL;
}
public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
}

public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
}
//***CREATE DATABASE***//
@Override
public void initDB(){
    mySQL.createDatabase();
}

//***HANDLE USERS***//
@Override
public String addUserToLogic(String userName){
    User user = new User(userName);
    setMsg("User not exist");
    Optional<User> userOp = Optional.of(user);
    userOp.ifPresent(u->{
        boolean isUserAdded=mySQL.addTable(user.getName());
        boolean isUserInDb=mySQL.getTableListfromDB().stream()
                                                 .anyMatch(l->l.equals(user.getName()));
        if(isUserInDb&&isUserAdded){
            userList.addComponent(user);
            setMsg("User added successfully");
        }else{
            setMsg("User not added to database");
        }
    });


    return msg;

}
```

This class implements list of users and required methods:
    public class UserList implements IComponentList {

```
//***CURRENT USER, LIST OF ALL USERS
private User currentUser; // this user is set in program as a current user
private ArrayList<User> usersList= new ArrayList<>();

//GETTERS AND SETTERS
public User getCurrentUser() {
    return currentUser;
}

public void setCurrentUser(User presentUser) {
    this.currentUser = presentUser;
}

//*This getter for userList is only for intern use in a UserList class*//
public ArrayList<User> getUserList() {
    return usersList;
}
public void setUserList(ArrayList<User> userList) {
    this.usersList = userList;
}
//***CONSTRUCTORS***//

public UserList(){

};

//***HANDLE USER LIST***//

//*This method return observable list (outside a class) which cointain all users *//
@Override
public ArrayList<User> getComponentList() {
    return getUserList();
}

//*This method add user to userList*//
@Override
public void addComponent(User component) {

    Optional<User> userOp = Optional.of(component);
    userOp.ifPresent(u->{
        getUserList().add(component);

    });
}
 This is class which define one user:
 public class User implements IComponent<User>,IComponentList<Goal>, Comparable<User> {

//***NAME, GOALLIST***//
private final String name;
private ArrayList<Goal> goalList;


//***GETTERS AND SETTERS//
@Override
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

//*This getter for goalList is only for intern use in a User class*//
private ArrayList<Goal> getGoalList() { 
    return goalList;
}
public void setGoalList(ArrayList<Goal> goalList) {
    this.goalList = goalList;
}
//***CONSTRUCTORS***//
public User(String name){
    this.name=name;

}
```

I don't added whole body of all classes. Because there is a lot more of code.
I add new user by addusercontroller, it is added to database, but i see that when i have open this window and i use method getList() i have different list than in maincontroller view. But I use one object modelLogic.

```
public abstract class MainController implements IHandleSerialization {
Object obj = new Object();
private ModelLogic modelLogic = new ModelLogic();
public ModelLogic getModelLogic() {
    return modelLogic;
}
```

MainPanelController:

```
   public class MainPanelController extends MainController implements   Initializable {

@FXML
private TopPanelController topPanelController;
public TopPanelController getTopPanelController() {
    return topPanelController;
}

@FXML
private MenuPanelController menuPanelController;

@FXML
private LeftPanelTimeModeController leftPanelTimeModeController;

@FXML
private CenterPanelTableController centerPanelTableController;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    getModelLogic().initDB();//if there is no database create it, otherwise not
    updateComboBox();
    showAddUserPanel();
    showRemoveUserPanel();
    setUser();


}
```

Comment: Time to fire up the debugger, set break points and find out what's happening as the program runs.

Comment: When you load the FXML, you get a new instance of the specified controller class, so of course it has its own instance of the data model.